# Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) with different sequences length inputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-2

I have different length input texts, from few character to hundred words so I decided to use different *MAX_LENGTH* for each batch instead of fix *MAX_LENGTH* for all batches (obviously shorter MAX_LENGTH for smaller text).

After googling I saw [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/40) thread in Keras github page which gave the following solution:

> Sequences should be grouped together by length, and segmented manually
>   into batches by that length before being sent to Keras.

If I use this trick, I'll guess there is no way to shuffle data at training time and it might lead to overfitting.

I saw many disscution in Kaggle that use this trick. I want to know is there any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the solution of **padding** your data with a dummy value, so all your input sequences have the same length.

Suppose you have these two sequences:

- [1,2,3,1,2], you keep it as [1,2,3,1,2]
- [1,3,2,3], you pad it with zeros until it reaches the desired length: [1,3,2,3,0]

Then you start your model with a [Masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) layer.

This will automatically ignore the additional length in the samples.